# Initializing floating point variable with large literal

Tags: c, floating-point

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    double x = 0.12345678901234567890123456789;
    printf("%0.16f\n", x);
    return 0;
};
```

In the code above I'm initializing `x` with literal that is too large to be represented by the IEEE 754 double. On my PC with gcc 4.9.2 it works well. The literal is rounded to the nearest value that fits into double. I'm wondering what happens behind the scene (on the compiler level) in this case? Does this behaviour depend on the platform? Is it legal?

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *6.4.4.2 Floating constants For decimal floating constants, and also for
hexadecimal floating constants when FLT_RADIX is not a power of 2, the result is either
the nearest representable value, or the larger or smaller representable value immediately
adjacent to the nearest representable value, chosen in an implementation-defined manner.
For hexadecimal floating constants when FLT_RADIX is a power of 2, the result is
correctly rounded.* tl;dr: The value of `x` does *not* have to the exactly-rounded literal.

Comment: @EOF Why not answer?

Comment: Floating point literal `0.12345678901234567890123456789;` is not large.  It is explicitly precise.  `1e123456789` is large.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write `double x = 0.1;`, the decimal number you have written is rounded to the nearest `double`. So what happens when you write `0.12345678901234567890123456789` is not fundamentally different.

The behavior is essentially implementation-defined, but most compilers will use the nearest representable `double` in place of the constant. The C standard [specifies](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.2p3) that it has to be either the `double` immediately above or the one immediately below.